# How to retrieve resource attributes whilst using OpenTelemetry Node.js SDK?

Tags: open-telemetry, otel, opentelemetry-js

The following code is inside a `instrumentation.js` file:

```js
const { NodeSDK } = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-node');
const sdk = new NodeSDK({
  resource: new Resource({
    [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'xyz',
    [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_VERSION]: '1.2.3',
  }),
  ...
}
sdk.start();
```

When running applications in production, a flag to `--require` the `instrumentation.js` is added to the `node` command,  as outlined in the [Getting Started > Node.js](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/js/getting-started/nodejs/#run-the-instrumented-app) documentation:

```
$ node --require ./instrumentation.js app.js
```

Application developers currently have no access to this `instrumentation.js` file.

**Is there a way for application developers to retrieve the resource attributes from within their applications (`app.js`) for logging, without access to `instrumentation.js`?**

---

1. If I have a reference to the resource, I can get the attributes using [`resource.attributes`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/blob/44b0b29dea98217130bc4e68d6c9b6901e75aef7/packages/opentelemetry-resources/src/Resource.ts#L90-L98). But how do I get a reference to that resource within the application?
2. `@opentelemetry/api` provides a [`getTracerProvider()`](https://open-telemetry.github.io/opentelemetry-js/classes/_opentelemetry_api.TraceAPI.html#getTracerProvider) method to get the current globally-registered `TracerProvider`. Is there an equivalent `getResource()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a [reply](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/4481#issuecomment-1943751474) from one of the maintainers of `opentelemetry-js`:

> As of today, the OpenTelemetry API specification does not include a way to retrieve the resource, therefore this is also not exposed in the JavaScript OTel API.